# Usage of com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner

Tags: java, xml, stax, woodstox

I am using woodstox-core-asl-4.1.0 to filter incoming XML to avoid DOS. But I am unable to find any tutorial to kick start with this API over Internet & even home page of http://woodstox.codehaus.org/
I have below queries :-

1. How to pass InputStream that hold XML data ?
2. How to use StreamScanner class with configuration to set Maximum Attribute Count ?

Looking for sample example that demonstrate how to use **woodstox API** to take **InputStream** & process it and how to configure it to address this use case **check if Attribute count of any XML element cross threshold**

Answer (score 0):

Woodstox implements Stax API: you can see JDK Javadocs for it (javax.xml.stream); as well as any Stax tutorial. You do NOT instantiate `StreamScanner` directly.

As to checking for attribute counts... make sure you understand how streaming parsers (SAX or Stax; in this case, latter) work. From that you can figure out how to check for number of attribute, for each `START_ELEMENT` you encounter.